# I don't see results of a self test of an SSD in smartctl

Tags: smartctl, nvme

I want to test my SSD. It seems that I can start a self test with smartctl, but when I try to display test's results, I don't see anything.

My SDD's model is *PNY CS3030 250GB SSD*:

```
$ lsblk -d -o name,model /dev/nvme0n1
NAME    MODEL
nvme0n1 PNY CS3030 250GB SSD
```

I make sure that SMART is enabled on it:

```
$ sudo smartctl -s on /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-121-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

NVMe device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

Then I start the test:

```
$ sudo smartctl -t short /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-121-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

NVMe device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

Then I try to see the results of the test - but smartctl does not display any:

```
$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-121-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

NVMe device successfully opened

Use 'smartctl -a' (or '-x') to print SMART (and more) information
```

And that's all. No information about any test running, having failed, nothing. I tried to repeat this command after an hour (maybe I should wait until the test is done), but still no result.

What's going on here?

Comment: try nvme-cli instead? smartctl has limited support for nvme devices

Answer (score 8):

`smartctl` doesn't quite work with NVMe drives except polling their current health status. Maybe it's going to support these things in the future but the current stable version 7.3 doesn't.

The self-test log can be fetched using this command (all the commands below must be run under root or sudo):

`nvme self-test-log /dev/nvme0`

`Self Test Codes` `1` and `2` correspond to short and extended self-tests, `Operation Result` `0` means the test completed error-free.

To run self-tests you have two options (actually [more](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli/issues/1252#issuecomment-977895224)):

```
nvme device-self-test /dev/nvme0 -s 2h # Start a extended device self-test operation
nvme device-self-test /dev/nvme0 -s 1h # Start a short device self-test operation
```

I had a sort of [chat](https://github.com/linux-nvme/nvme-cli/issues/1252) with an NVME developer a year ago, that's where I got all this information from. Now it's available in man pages (for `nvme-cli` version 2.0 and higher) but not in all distros.